# Why does not work callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an function that remove element from Redis store:

```
function removeDevice(identificator, callback){
    client.srem('devices', identificator, function(err) {
        callback(true);
    });
}
```

And I call this:

```
removeDevice(function (data) {
        res.json(data);
    });
```

It gives me error:

TypeError: callback is not a function on the line:

```
callback(true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing in the function as the **first** argument (`identificator`), not the second (`callback`):

There's only one argument here:

```
removeDevice(function (data) {
    res.json(data);
});
```

For the callback to the second argument, there'd have to be one in front of it:

```
removeDevice(somethingHere, function (data) {
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    res.json(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function expects 2 parameters.

```
function removeDevice(identificator, callback){
```

However, you are passing only 1 parameter, hence, `identificator` holds the value of function passed